# User does not have permission=SEND with custom JAAS module in Artemis 2.10.1

Tags: jms, jaas, activemq-artemis

I am using custom JAAS module with required configuration changes in `login.config`, `artemis.profile` and `broker.xml`.

**login.config**:

```
activemq { test.JaasLoginModule required debug=false; };
```

**JaasLoginModule.java**:

```java
    public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
        if (succeeded) {
            principals.add(new UserPrincipal("test_user"));
            principals.add(new RolePrincipal("amq"));//setting the role
            subject.getPrincipals().addAll(principals);
        }
        return succeeded;
    }
    public boolean login() throws LoginException {
     //Here I am returning true with the hardcoded user details
    }
}
```

**artemis.profile**:

```
JAVA_ARGS="-XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms512M -Xmx2G -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.offline="true" -Dhawtio.role=amq -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=test.RolePrincipal -Djolokia.policyLocation=${ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI}jolokia-access.xml"
```

**broker.xml**:

```xml
<security-settings>
   <security-setting match="#">
      <permission roles="amq" type="createAddress"/>
      <permission roles="amq" type="send"/>
   </security-setting>
</security-settings>
```

Here is the client code:

```java
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
p.put("connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory", "tcp://localhost:61616");
p.put("queue.queue/testQueue", "testQueue");
initialContext = new InitialContext(p);
Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/testQueue");
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
connection = cf.createConnection("test_user", "Test#123");
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/testQueue");
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("This is a text message");
producer.send(message);
```

I am getting below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ229032: User:**** does not have permission='SEND' on address testQueue
```

Comment: login.config : activemq {
   test.JaasLoginModule required
   debug=false;
};

Comment: broker.xml :                                                                                                  
  <security-settings>
    <security-setting match="#">
            <permission roles="amq" type="createAddress"/> <permission roles="amq" type="send"/>
         </security-setting>
</security-settings>

Comment: artemis.prfile : # Java Opts
JAVA_ARGS=" -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms512M -Xmx2G -Dhawtio.realm=activemq  -Dhawtio.offline="true" -Dhawtio.role=amq -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=test.RolePrincipal -Djolokia.policyLocation=${ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI}jolokia-access.xml"

Comment: Hi Justin, my objective is to use custom JAAS module to authenticate clients for sending messages. For that I have created a broker use artemis command line and then make the required changes to test that. After deploying the JAAS module I use simple JMS code to create queue and send messages. Initially I was getting error while creating queue so, I have made changes to create queue using admin(original) authorization and then try to send messages using my JMS client. Could you please help ?

Comment: "hawtio.role" is default one which is amq. Trying to see how can I send code for client and test.JaasLoginModule

Comment: Here is the client code : Properties p = new Properties();
   p.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
   p.put("connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory", "tcp://localhost:61616");
   p.put("queue.queue/testQueue", "testQueue");
   initialContext = new InitialContext(p);
   Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/testQueue");
   ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
   connection = cf.createConnection("test_user", "Test#123");//first

Comment: Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);//second
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

Comment: It looks like your client code is missing the part where it actually sends the message and triggers the authorization failure. In any case, can you please confirm that your login module is actually associating `test_user` with the `amq` role? I suspect it is not doing this which is causing the failure.

Comment: Hi Justin, I have added JaasLogin module where I hardcode the user with role.

Comment: @JustinBertram, I try to follow the artemis doccumentation to tie the user with role. But, I am clueless here, what exactly I am missing. If I use default authentication of the broker("admin","admin"), I am able to create and send messages.

Comment: Where are you setting `succeeded = true`? It would be good to have all the code for your login module.

Comment: Without more details I can't help.

Comment: Hi Justin, sorry for the delayed reply. I was working on fixing this issue. Thanks again for all your inputs. I am able to configure the broker instance with configurable JAAS module. I was using my own UserPrincipal and RolePrincipal instead of using this two classes from Artemis API. Once I use these two classes from org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.* in my JaasLoginModule it worked.

Comment: I will update this page with details answer. Thanks a lot for your help and inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. My custom JAAS module loaded into artemis and able to authenticate and authorize client for messaging. The reason my module was not working is because I was using my custom `RolePrincipal` class in the JAAS module:

```
-Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=test.UserPrincipal
```

If I use the one from Artemis API, it works fine.

```
-Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.UserPrincipal
```

**artemis.profile**:

```
JAVA_ARGS="-XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms512M -Xmx2G -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.offline="true" -Dhawtio.role=amq -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.UserPrincipal -Djolokia.policyLocation=${ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI}jolokia-access.xml"
```